# Problem with the caption position for tables

Tags: captions

I'm a new learner so I don't know how can I solve this problem:
I used `\documentclass{itor}`. the caption must be in 2 different lines and left side (fig 1).
I have a small table and the caption isn't in the correct position because of the table size (fig 2).
I want to fix the caption exactly above the table and left side.
how can I shift the caption without using `\usepackage{caption}`? because this package changing the format of all captions.

Thanks for your attention.

[image]

```
\documentclass{itor}
\usepackage{natbib}%
\usepackage[figuresright]{rotating}
\usepackage{url}
\urlstyle{same}
\usepackage{algorithmic}
\usepackage{algorithm}
\usepackage{amsmath,amsthm}
\newtheorem{theorem}{Theorem}
\newtheorem{lemma}{Lemma}
\newtheorem{property}{Property}
\theoremstyle{definition}
\newtheorem{example}{Example}
\newtheorem{remark}{Remark}
\theoremstyle{remark}
\newtheorem{definition}{Definition}
\begin{document}\raggedbottom
\begin{table}
\centering
\caption{Experimental values for parameters \label{tab:experiments}}
\begin{tabular}{lll}
\hline
\tch{1}{l}{instances}  & \tch{1}{l}{Iteration} & \tch{1}{l}{$\alpha$}\\
\hline
SP3,SP5,SP8,SP10,SP12 & 10,2030 & 10.20.30\\
LP1,LP3,LP6,LP13,LP14 & 20,50.100 & 20.30.40\\
\hline
\end{tabular}
\end{table}
\end{document}
```

Comment: Welcome to TeX SX! The problem is that the `itor` class is not a standard class (nor `\tch`a standard command, b.t.w.).

Comment: ...put differently, adele, where can we find `itor.cls`?